# Dynamic pivot: sum of sales per month

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql

My table is like this:

```
Sitecode    Month  Amount
--------    -----  ------
XX          Jan     1000
XX          Jan     3000
XX          Apr     3000
XX          Apr     1000
```

What I want is, to show the result something like this:

```
Sitecode    MonthJAN   MonthAPR
--------    --------   --------
XX          4000       4000
```

Comment: Check this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39000.sql-script-convert-rows-to-columns-using-dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server.aspx

Answer (score 19):

As others have said this is known as a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). There are several ways in which you can transform your data from rows into columns of data.

If you know the values ahead of time, then you can hard-code the values. Prior to the `PIVOT` function you would use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement.

**Aggregate/CASE Version:**

```
select sitecode,
  sum(case when [month] = 'Jan' then amount else 0 end) MonthJan,
  sum(case when [month] = 'Apr' then amount else 0 end) MonthApr
from yourtable
group by sitecode;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73b2f/4).

The `PIVOT` function was made available in SQL Server 2005, so if you are using that version or a newer one then you can apply that to your data.

**Static PIVOT:**

```
select *
from
(
  select sitecode,
    [month],
    amount
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  sum(amount)
  for month in (Jan, Apr)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07d60/2)

The above two versions work great if you know the values ahead of time. If not, then you will use dynamic sql to create the result.

**Dynamic PIVOT:**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(month) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT sitecode,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select sitecode, [month], amount
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(amount)
                for month in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07d60/1)

All 3 versions of this will return the same result:

```
| SITECODE |  JAN |  APR |
--------------------------
|       XX | 4000 | 4000 |
```

Answer (score 9):

As Martin Smith said, you need to pivot the data, whether with an explicit PIVOT as referenced or something like this [(SQL Fiddle)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e801/1):

```
SELECT SiteCode
   , SUM(Case When Month='Jan' Then Amount Else 0 End) MonthJan
   , SUM(Case When Month='Apr' Then Amount Else 0 End) MonthApr
FROM Result GROUP BY SiteCode;
```