# How to do a SELECT inside of a PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to SELECT values from a column in my database in order to perform a PIVOT on those values without hard-coding them.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ItemType, [Status] FROM [EVAULTTEST].[dbo].EvidenceItems WHERE ItemType IS NOT NULL) AS ei

PIVOT(
COUNT([Status])
FOR [Status] 
    IN (SELECT DISTINCT ei.[Status] FROM [EVAULTTEST].[dbo].EvidenceItems AS ei)
) AS piv
```

However, the SELECT inside of our IN is giving us the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'. Expecting '.', ID, or QUOTED_ID.
```

How can we use a SELECT inside of a FOR IN statement?

Comment: You can't, you have to use dynamic SQL. PIVOT requires that the columns be known when the command is executed.  See this question - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31760/display-month-in-columns-and-the-sum-of-sales-below-the-columns-in-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty much what bluefeet gave you as an example in the comments.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Status]) 
                    from [EVAULTTEST].[dbo].EvidenceItems
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [ItemType],' + @cols + ' from 
             (SELECT ItemType, [Status]
                from [EVAULTTEST].[dbo].EvidenceItems) x
            pivot 
            (COUNT([Status])
                for [Status] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```