# Sql server complex select query row as column

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server:

Table1:

[image: Table1]

Table2:

[image: Table2]

I need a select query to give me output like this:

[image: Required Output]

I am attaching here the sample data of two tables in text format since I am unable to add the Excel sheets here

#### Table1

| SCHOOL_ID | TEACHER_ID | IS_HEAD_MASTER | TAGGED_CLASS | IMAGE_NAME | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE | ACCURACY | CREATED_DATE | CREATED_BY | AI_IMAGE_NAME | AI_STATUS | IS_DOWNLOADED | DOWNLOADED_DATE | IS_PROCESSEED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 204 | 341 | Y |  | 10.jpeg | 1.1 | 2.1 | 80 | 49:33.0 | 28110100204 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16:54.0 | NULL |
| 204 | 341 | Y |  | 20.jpeg | 1.1 | 2.1 | 80 | 49:33.0 | 28110100204 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16:54.0 | NULL |
| 204 | 341 | Y |  | 30.jpeg | 1.1 | 2.1 | 80 | 49:33.0 | 28110100204 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16:54.0 | NULL |
| 204 | 734 | N |  | 40.jpeg | 1.2 | 2.2 | 90 | 55:59.3 | 28110100204 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16:54.0 | NULL |
| 204 | 734 | N |  | 50.jpeg | 1.2 | 2.2 | 90 | 55:59.3 | 28110100204 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16:54.0 | NULL |
| 204 | 734 | N |  | 60.jpeg | 1.2 | 2.2 | 90 | 55:59.3 | 28110100204 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16:54.0 | NULL |

#### Table2

| TEACHER_ID | TAGGED_SCHOOL_ID | ATTENDANCE_DT | ATTENDANCE_TYPE | IMAGE_NAME | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE | ACCURACY | CAPTURED_TIME | AI_IMAGE_NAME | AI_STATUS | IS_DOWNLOADED | DOWNLOADED_DATE | IS_PROCESSEED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 341 | 204 | 21/02/2022 | IN | 1.jpeg | 1.1 | 2.1 | 80 | 37:16.0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 341 | 204 | 21/02/2022 | OUT | 2.jpeg | 1.2 | 2.2 | 80 | 55:45.0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 734 | 204 | 21/02/2022 | IN | 3.jpeg | 1.3 | 2.3 | 80 | 24:24.0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 734 | 204 | 21/02/2022 | OUT | 4.jpeg | 1.4 | 2.4 | 80 | 31:47.0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I have written below query but it is not giving the output in required format:

```
select t1.TEACHER_ID as "t1.TEACHER_ID", t2.TEACHER_ID as "t2.TEACHER_ID", 
STRING_AGG(t1.IMAGE_NAME,', ') as "t1.IMAGE_NAME", STRING_AGG(t2.IMAGE_NAME,', ') as 
"t2.IMAGE_NAME" from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.TEACHER_ID=t2.TEACHER_ID GROUP BY 
t1.TEACHER_ID=t2.TEACHER_ID;
```

Please help me to solve my query issue.

It's part of my ML work. Once I will get the records in required format, I will use the images in further process. Currently I am struggling with select query part.

*Table1* and *Table2* are just dummy names. Obviously, the actual table names and data are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given data:

```
DECLARE @Table1 table 
(
    TeacherID integer NOT NULL, 
    ImageName varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @Table2 table
(
    TeacherID integer NOT NULL, 
    ImageName varchar(20) NOT NULL    
);

INSERT @Table1
    (TeacherID, ImageName)
VALUES
    (341, '10.jpeg'),
    (341, '20.jpeg'),
    (341, '30.jpeg'),
    (734, '40.jpeg'),
    (734, '50.jpeg'),
    (734, '60.jpeg');

INSERT @Table2
    (TeacherID, ImageName)
VALUES
    (341, '1.jpeg'),
    (341, '2.jpeg'),
    (734, '3.jpeg'),
    (734, '4.jpeg');
```

The basic idea is:

```
WITH 
    CombinedData AS
    (
        -- Get data from both sources
        SELECT T1.TeacherID, T1.ImageName
        FROM @Table1 AS T1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT T2.TeacherID, T2.ImageName
        FROM @Table2 AS T2
    ),
    ImageNumbers AS
    (
        -- Extract just the numbers from the ImageName
        -- for ordering purposes next
        SELECT
            CD.TeacherID, 
            CD.ImageName,
            ImageNumber = CONVERT(integer, 
                REPLACE(CD.ImageName, '.jpeg', ''))
        FROM CombinedData AS CD
    ),
    NumberedRows AS
    (
        -- Number the rows for each TeacherID
        -- in ImageNumber order
        -- These will be column numbers after the pivot
        SELECT 
            I.TeacherID, 
            I.ImageName,
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY I.TeacherID
                ORDER BY I.ImageNumber)
        FROM ImageNumbers AS I
    )
-- Pivot the data
SELECT
    P.TeacherID, 
    Image1 = P.[1],
    Image2 = P.[2], 
    Image3 = P.[3], 
    Image4 = P.[4], 
    Image5 = P.[5]
FROM NumberedRows
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(ImageName) 
    FOR RowNum IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
) AS P;
```

Results:

| TeacherID | Image1 | Image2 | Image3 | Image4 | Image5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 341 | 1.jpeg | 2.jpeg | 10.jpeg | 20.jpeg | 30.jpeg |
| 734 | 3.jpeg | 4.jpeg | 40.jpeg | 50.jpeg | 60.jpeg |

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f13a1d6fcc49e56e1ef8dcd800639c5)

If you need a *dynamic* pivot because you don't know in advance how many columns there will be, see:

- [Need help with SQL Server PIVOT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/63698/1192)
- [Dynamic pivot: sum of sales per month](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/31760/1192)